# Angular - Validate numeric input field in the reactive form for specific range

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

In Angular form, there is a numeric input field. Here minimum value should be 3 and the max value is 10. When the form is loading, the default value should be 0. It means the user should be able to put 0 or values between 3 and 10. But my implementation gives an error when I send the form with the default value of 0. How can I solve this?

HTML page

```
<form #ConfigForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="sampleform" (ngSubmit)="onSendHandler()">
    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field" appearance="outline">
    <input matInput formControlName="numValue"/>
    <mat-error *ngIf="sampleform.get('numValue').hasError('pattern')">Numbers Only ! 
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="sampleform.get('numValue').hasError('min')">Min Value is 
    3</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="sampleform.get('numValue').hasError('max')">Max Value is 
    10</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

.ts file

```js
//set default values
this.sampleform.patchValue({
  numValue: 0
});

sampleform = new FormGroup({
numValue: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"), Validators.min(3), 
Validators.max(10)])
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `ValidatorFn` which check the default value and range validators as below:

```js
defaultValueOrRangeValidator(
  defaultValue: number,
  ...rangeValidators: ValidatorFn[]
): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control.value == defaultValue) return null;

    for (let validator of rangeValidators) {
      if (validator(control)) return validator(control);
    }
  };
}
```

```js
this.sampleform = new FormGroup({
  numValue: new FormControl('', [
    ...
    this.defaultValueOrRangeValidator(
      0,
      Validators.min(3),
      Validators.max(10)
    ),
  ]),
});
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkfdft?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Its not working with input typ="number"

Comment: Would be great if you can create another question by providing a minimal reproducible (StackBlitz) example. As normally the answer is written based on the question.